# DWR + Spring + JPA Session Closed

Tags: spring, session, jpa, dwr

**Background**

The application I am working on currently uses Spring + JPA. Everything was working fine before we decided to introduce DWR.

Using DWR I invoke a method on a Service class and it then redirects to the Controller.

```
try{
      return WebContextFactory.get()
                        .forwardToString("/search.do?searchString=" + searchString);
}catch(...){

}
```

After this, when the search method is invoked at the DAO, it does not find an pen session.

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
```

This session here is closed...

I think my changes(of introducing DWR) should not in any way affect the Session creation.

Awaiting inputs.

Shardul.

Comment: How are your database sessions handled?

Comment: I use connection pooling, if that is what you meant to ask. Another thing I noticed is that it seems as if the request sent to the Controller using WebContextFactory.... is somehow unable to bind to the existing EntityManager and it tries to create a new EntityManager...it later closes the EntityManager...

I am posting the trace next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved.

The problem was with the configuration of OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in the web.xml. It was not intercepting the DWR requests as it was mapped to a

> *.do

instead of

> /*

Shardul.